# Programmatically identify SDK and normal version

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I wanted to identify if node-webkit is in SDK or normal version.
Is there a way to do this at code level?

Comment: seems like no update on this. :(

Comment: In case someone bump into this: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/5062